# Issue Inserting hebrew in mysql table from a batch file

Tags: mysql, sql, collation, hebrew

When i run the sql script, the hebrew data in mysql table appears to be garbage like `"ÎíÎ£ÎòÎæÎºÎÖÎö ,ÎÆÎƒ ÎöÎóÎôÎƒ Î®Î£ ÎÉÎÖÎ¿ÎòÎñÎö".`

the table collation is `**utf8_general_ci**` in table as well as database.

Here is my sql script

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_lang` (
  `name` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `hebrew` text
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `tbl_lang` (`name`, `hebrew`) VALUES
('Title', 'סלובקיה ,גן העדן של אירופה'),
('Form', 'טופס הצעת מחיר');
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: This question have no relation with the Windows/DOS Batch .BAT `batch-file` tag. Please, remove such tag from your question...

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the character encoding to utf8 as well as the collation.

You can do it from the `shell` like this:

```
ALTER TABLE Table CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Answer (score 0):

Mojibake -- Probably

- The bytes you have in the client are correctly encoded in utf8 (good).
- You connected with `SET NAMES latin1` (or `set_charset('latin1')` or ...), probably by default.  (It should have been `utf8`.)
- The column in the tables may or may not have been `CHARACTER SET utf8`, but it should have been that.

In order to get `ÎíÎ£ÎòÎæÎºÎÖÎö ,ÎÆÎƒ ÎöÎóÎôÎƒ Î®Î£ ÎÉÎÖÎ¿ÎòÎñÎö`, somehow cp850 was involved.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following in your batch (.sh) job :

```
--default-character-set=hebrew
```

I run the following .sh job :

```
mysql -uMY_USER --password=MY_PASSWORD --database=MY_DB --default-character-set=hebrew < '/home/test1/public_html/my_files/my_updates.sql'
```

in the my_updates.sql file I have update commands with Hebrew characters :

```
UPDATE `GADI` SET `g_name`='אבגדהוזחטי' WHERE `g_id`=2;
```

and as long as I have the **--default-character-set=hebrew** - the Hebrew in the table comes out just fine.